# Closed form of integral of $\operatorname{erfc} \log t$

Tags: statistics, integration, special-functions, definite-integrals, closed-form

Is there any closed form expression for the following integral?

$$ \int\limits_t^\infty \left(1- \operatorname{erf}(\log x) \right )dx $$

or equivalently:

$$ \int\limits_t^\infty \operatorname{erfc}(\log x ) dx $$

I just wish to know if there is any way I can do better than sampling the values at particular points and calculating the area under the curve numerically. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please, [don't yell!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing).

Comment: sorry for that, my bad! did not notice!!

Comment: @Sand I edited. To introduce a new operator or function name use `\operatorname{blah}`

Comment: thanks anon. I hope its fine now.

Comment: Mathematica can evaluate this explicitly as $$e^{1/4} \operatorname{erfc}\left(\log t-\frac{1}{2}\right) - t \operatorname{erfc}(\log t)$$ for $t \geq 0$.

Comment: Those two are not equivalent.  The first integrand approaches $0$ as $x\to\infty$.  The second one approaches $1$.

Comment: @Michael, the first integrand involves "erf" and the second involves "erfc".

Comment: hey, thanks for your help. By the way, I tried to compute it symbolically in MATLAB, but it did not work out. I just hope that the given formula works. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not terribly hard; one only needs simple substitutions and an application of integration by parts here. To wit,

$$\begin{align*}
\int_t^\infty \mathrm{erfc}(\log u)\,\mathrm du&=\int_{\log\,t}^\infty \exp\,v\;\mathrm{erfc}\,v\,\mathrm dv\\
&=\left.\exp\,v\;\mathrm{erfc}\,v\right|_{\log\,t}^\infty+\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\int_{\log\,t}^\infty \exp\,(v-v^2)\,\mathrm dv\\
&=-t\;\mathrm{erfc}(\log\,t)+\frac{2\sqrt[4]{e}}{\sqrt\pi}\int_{\log\,t-\frac12}^\infty \exp\,(-w^2)\,\mathrm dw\\
&=\sqrt[4]{e}\,\mathrm{erfc}\left(\log\,t-\frac12\right)-t\;\mathrm{erfc}(\log\,t)\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: thanks for the step by step derivation.